# Show that the system of all matrices of the special form is isomorphic to the field of complex number.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Show that the system of all matrices of the special form

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \alpha & \beta \\
    -\beta & \alpha \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

combined by matrix addition and matrix multiplication, is isomorphic to the field of complex number.

How do i start showing this ?

And first of all how can matrix have a one to one connection with complex numbers

Answer (score 0):

An isomorphism is given by $$\begin{bmatrix}\alpha&\beta\\-\beta&\alpha\end{bmatrix}\mapsto\alpha+\beta i.$$ Another isomorphism is given by $$\begin{bmatrix}\alpha&\beta\\-\beta&\alpha\end{bmatrix}\mapsto\alpha-\beta i.$$ You just need to show that one of the maps really does preserve addition, multiplication and multiplicative identity.

(**Edit**: You may want to ask how I come up with these two maps, or why do we even consider the matrices of such form in the first place. If you want, I can add details.)

(**Edit 2**: You need to show the map is bijective as well.)

**Added**: To show it preserves multiplication, you are trying the prove the equality $$F\left(\begin{bmatrix}\alpha&\beta\\-\beta&\alpha \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\gamma&\sigma\\-\sigma&\gamma \end{bmatrix}\right)=F\left(\begin{bmatrix}\alpha&\beta\\-\beta&\alpha \end{bmatrix}\right)F\left(\begin{bmatrix}\gamma&\sigma\\-\sigma&\gamma \end{bmatrix}\right)$$ holds, where $$F\left(\begin{bmatrix}\alpha&\beta\\-\beta&\alpha \end{bmatrix}\right)=\alpha+\beta i.$$ It is just a slightly tedious calculation: $$F\left(\begin{bmatrix}\alpha&\beta\\-\beta&\alpha \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\gamma&\sigma\\-\sigma&\gamma \end{bmatrix}\right)=F\left(\begin{bmatrix}\alpha\gamma-\beta\sigma&\alpha\sigma+\beta\gamma\\-(\beta\gamma+\alpha\sigma)&-\beta\sigma+\alpha\gamma\end{bmatrix}\right)=\color{red}{(\alpha\gamma-\beta\sigma)+(\alpha\sigma+\beta\gamma)i},\\ F\left(\begin{bmatrix}\alpha&\beta\\-\beta&\alpha \end{bmatrix}\right)F\left(\begin{bmatrix}\gamma&\sigma\\-\sigma&\gamma \end{bmatrix}\right)=(\alpha+\beta i)(\gamma+\sigma i)=\color{red}{(\alpha\gamma-\beta\sigma)+(\alpha\sigma+\beta\gamma)i}.$$

As for how we came up with the isomorphisms, we may do this algebraically:

1. Multiplicative identity must be mapped to multiplicative identity. In this case, the identity matrix must be mapped to $1+0i$.
2. The complex polynomial equation $z^2+1=0$ has complex number solutions $i$ and $-i$. If there is isomorphism from the set of matrices to complex numbers, it means the matrix polynomial equation $X^2+I=\boldsymbol0$ has two solutions $$\begin{bmatrix}\alpha&\beta\\-\beta&\alpha\end{bmatrix},\ \begin{bmatrix}-\alpha&-\beta\\\beta&-\alpha\end{bmatrix}$$ where $I$ is the identity matrix, $\boldsymbol0$ is the zero matrix, and the two solutions shall be mapped to $i$ and $-i$ by an isomorphism. When you solve the matrix polynomial equation, you would find out the two unknowns $\alpha,\beta$ has to satisfy $$\begin{cases}\alpha^2-\beta^2=-1\\2\alpha\beta=0\end{cases}.$$ This would mean $\beta$ cannot be zero ($\alpha^2=-1$ cannot hold for a real number $\alpha$), $\alpha$ must be zero, and $\beta=1$ or $\beta=-1$.
3. The facts that isomorphism preserves real scalar multiplication (if you do consider scalar multiplication), and that $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ is sent to  $1$, $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}$ is sent to $i$ or $-i$, force us to define $$\begin{bmatrix}\alpha&\beta\\-\beta&\alpha\end{bmatrix}\mapsto\alpha+\beta i$$ or $$\begin{bmatrix}\alpha&\beta\\-\beta&\alpha\end{bmatrix}\mapsto\alpha-\beta i.$$

As for why we came up with these matrices of special form, it follows from a fact about complex number multiplication: multiplication by a complex number is the same as doing a proper rotation and then a scaling. The matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}\alpha&\beta\\-\beta&\alpha\end{bmatrix}$$ represents a linear transformation that does a rotation and then a scaling. You may notice that the matrix may be written as $$\begin{bmatrix}r\cos\theta&r\sin\theta\\-r\sin\theta&r\cos\theta\end{bmatrix},$$ where $r$ is the scaling factor and $\theta$ is the rotation angle. This is a whole new story I won't extend further.

Comment: And how do i show that it preserves the multiplicative identity ?

Comment: Yeah please add

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\mapsto1+0 i=1.$

Answer (score 0):

It will be sum of kronecker product of

1. $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ and $\alpha$
2. $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\beta$

By block multiplication property of matrices:

1. the 1 behaves as a real $1$
2. the 2 behaves as an imaginary $i$.

1) should be obvious.

We can verify 2) by calculating it's first few powers up to 4 to see it shifts through $-1,-i,1,\cdots$ corresponding to $\begin{bmatrix}-1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix} ,\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ above.